# Why do I now get the error ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template user_mailer -- when the template exists already?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

On my application I have been successfully sending out email messages, until today. When I run the rake task or run the method mannually from the console, I get the following error:

```
UserMailer#admin_test: processed outbound mail in 23.6ms
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template user_mailer/admin_test         with "mailer". Searched in:
* "user_mailer"
```

This would lead me to check if there is a template, which there is in `user_mailer/admin_test.html.erb` and `user_mailer/admin_test.text.erb` .

My method in `user_mailer.rb` is:

```
def admin_test(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Text")
end
```

Running `UserMailer.admin_test(@user).deliver_now!` (or just `deliver!`) renders this error. I initially came upon it running it as a rake task from the scheduler and this error is also replicated straight up from the console.

**EDIT**

Here's the rest of the error message:

```
from /Users/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:915:in `each_template'
```

**EDIT 2**

Okay - so I pushed the current form to heroku and it is **working** in production but **not** in development.

Comment: anything else showing up in the production.log? Any errors in any other server logs? Have you pushed any new updates? Has anything else changed?

Comment: I report the very same issue: same error message in development but works in production. The only thing I changed is I installed brakeman gem recently.